# The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) int, String

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i have got an error 'The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) int, String'

Comment: can you post a code example please.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("»")).click();                                            int PageCount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='TableData']/app-root/div[2]/table/tfoot/tr/td/[" + index_02 + "]")).size();
System.out.println("The total page count is : "+PageCount);
           driver.findElement(By.linkText("«")).click(); while(index_01<=PageCount)                                                                                             Showing error in 2nd line

Comment: You cannot format lines of code in a comment. Please edit your original post and format the code correctly. My solution below should solve the problem anyway.

Comment: If the solution below solved the problem please mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are comparing a primitive type (int) with a String object. These two variables cannot be compared directly.

To compare a String representing a number (e.g. `"50"`) with an integer, first convert it to an int with `Integer.parseInt(String)`

Example

```
String stringNumber = "123";
int intNumber = 100;
if (Integer.parseInt(stringNumber) <= intNumber){
    // stringNumber converted to int is less than intNumber
}
```

Using the code you posted, assuming index_01 is a String:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("»")).click();
int PageCount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='TableData']/app-root‌​/div[2]/table/tfoot/‌​tr/td/[" + index_02 + "]")).size();
System.out.println("The total page count is : "+PageCount);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("«")).click(); 
while(Integer.parseInt(index_01) <= PageCount){ .... }
```